# Get age from date of birth Angularjs in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

```
 <tr ng-repeat="player in team.players">
          <td>{{player.dateOfBirth}}</td>
...
```

From this I get back a date of birth in this format: 1987-01-24. How can I get the age from this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your controller:

```
$scope.calculateAge = function(birthday) { // pass in player.dateOfBirth
    var ageDifMs = Date.now() - new Date(birthday);
    var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs); // miliseconds from epoch
    return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
}
```

Then, simply use as your model:

```
<tr ng-repeat="player in team.players">
    <td ng-model="calculateAge(player.dateOfBirth)"></td>
```

Comment: That this be a filter

Comment: Whats the purpose of 1970 in return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);

Comment: @Pankaj when you create a new date from the difference of age (i.e. `ageDate`), you do so by adding a number of milliseconds to the start of Unix/Epoch time. This time starts at 01/01/1970 with a millisecond value of 0. So, we subtract the number of years that `ageDate` has from `1970` to get the total number of years that the millisecond value represents.

Answer (score 2):

**HTML**

```
<td>{{ player.dateOfBirth | ageFilter }}</td>
```

**JS**

```
app.filter('ageFilter', function () {
    function calculateAge (birthday) { // birthday is a date
        var date = new Date(birthday);
        var ageDifMs = Date.now() - date.getTime();
        var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs); // miliseconds from epoch
        return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
    }

    return function (birthdate) {
        return calculateAge(birthdate);
    };
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/uyvpLjv0/)**

Comment: thanks! so should I put it in the controller or create a filter?

Comment: I'd suggest a filter for reusability and testability (you can test this as a filter and not have to test it every controller you use it in)

Comment: I've fixed it and there's a jsfiddle